# Why static fields not serialized using google.gson.GsonBuilder JSON parser?

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, static

I tried *serializing* an object using **google.gson.GsonBuilder** as follows:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static String ToJson(Object o, Type oType)
    {
        Gson gson = new().setPrettyPrinting().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
        gson.toJson(o, oType);
    }
}

public class JsonTest
{
   public static String staticField;

   public static String ToJson()
   {
       JsonTest newJsonTest = new JsonTest();
       newJsonTest.staticField = TelephoneStatus.GetPhoneIMEI(); // let's say we use static field to keep IMEI

       Type oType = new TypeToken<JsonTest>(){}.getType();
       return JsonHelper.ToJson(newJsonTest, oType);
   }
}
```

*Return value* for `JsonTest` class method `ToJson()` is empty. If i change `staticField` field declaration to be **non-static**, it works as expected. Considering why static fields are not serialized, should it be considered as a **bug**? Or is it considered unnecessary?

If i had a *list* of `JsonTest` i wouldn't expect having static field parsed and written *multiple times* but *once*. However, isn't it better than missing it at all?

Comment: From what I remember even standard serialization omits static fields since they don't belong to single object but to entire class. Probably google.gson.GsonBuilder works this way for the same reason.

Comment: Hey Pshemo thanks for comment. They don't belong to single object instance but entire class. Instance belongs entire class. So isn't a static field still related with instance?

Comment: `Static` fields are not `serializable` because static fields are `class variables`, they are not specific for particular `instance` of that class. In fact all `objects` of that class share same `static` variable i.e. If change is done in `static` variable then this change will be reflected to all the `objects`. If static variable is made serializable then it will become object specific which contradicts the definition of `static` variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java Serialization only serialize object's non-static and non-transient fields because,

> The defaultReadObject method uses information in the stream to assign
>   the fields of the object saved in the stream with the correspondingly
>   named fields in the current object. This handles the case when the
>   class has evolved to add new fields. The method does not need to
>   concern itself with the state belonging to its superclasses or
>   subclasses. State is saved by writing the individual fields to the
>   ObjectOutputStream using the writeObject method or by using the
>   methods for primitive data types supported by DataOutput.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

In case of static field state not only belongs to any specific object it will belongs to all class.

So the static field would be comes under state of any specific object.

Comment: The whole serialization concept is same as well and that is applicable to all. :)

Comment: So you assert. You can't prove that by quoting one of the other systems. You need to quote the *relevant* documentation.

Answer (score 19):

but if someone wants to **include static**, change the builder to just ignore transient, since you will override the the default of both transient and static to just transient.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder  = new GsonBuilder();
// Allowing the serialization of static fields    

gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT);
    // Creates a Gson instance based on the current configuration
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    String json = gson.toJson(objectToSerialize);
    System.out.println(json);
```