# Gson & Java - Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: ..... Forgot to register a type adapter?

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to create an abstract class for defining configuration classes. I wish to export and import these classes from and to JSON whenever I want to. I'm trying to achieve this using Gson.

I'm getting an error when writing to JSON that states it:

> can't serialize java.lang.Class - Forgot to register a type adapter?

My main class: https://hastebin.com/pogohodovi.scala
Abstract config class: https://hastebin.com/adeyawubuy.cs

An example of a child class:

```
public class DyescapeCOREConfiguration extends DyescapeConfiguration {

    private static transient DyescapeCOREConfiguration i = new DyescapeCOREConfiguration();
    public static DyescapeCOREConfiguration get() { return i; }

    @Expose public static String ServerID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

}
```

Please note: I need to keep the variables in the child configuration classes static. I tried to create some adapters/serializers, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Ofcourse, here you go: [link](https://hastebin.com/ufaduyojor.md)

Comment: This seems to be the offending line: `DyescapeCORE.get().getDyescapeCOREGSonBuilder().create().toJson(this.getClass(), writer);` which uses the method: [`Gson.toJson(Object, Writer)`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Appendable-) it looks like there is no default adapter to serialize a `java.lang.Class`, so you'd have to write one yourself. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026751/why-has-gson-does-not-allow-serialization-of-java-lang-class

Comment: Please include the stacktrace and code in the question itself, not as links

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably doing:

```java
gson.toJson(DyescapeCOREConfiguration.class)
```

In order to serialize this class, you still must create an instance of `DyescapeCOREConfiguration`. Since `static`s are not (de)serialized by default, you have to [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666187/166589) them (IMHO, enabling such modifier is really not a good idea):

```
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(TRANSIENT) // STATIC|TRANSIENT in the default configuration
            .create();
    final String json = gson.toJson(new DyescapeCOREConfiguration());
    System.out.println(json);
```

The output:

> {"ServerID":"37145480-64b9-4beb-b031-2d619f14a44b"}

---

### Update

If obtaining an instance is not possible for whatever reason, write a custom `Class<?>` type adapter (I would never use it in practice):

#### StaticTypeAdapterFactory.java

```java
final class StaticTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory staticTypeAdapterFactory = new StaticTypeAdapterFactory();

    private StaticTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getStaticTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return staticTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final Type type = typeToken.getType();
        if ( type.equals(Class.class) ) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> castStaticTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) getStaticTypeAdapter(gson);
            return castStaticTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

#### StaticTypeAdapter.java

```
final class StaticTypeAdapter<T>
        extends TypeAdapter<Class<T>> {

    private static final String TARGET_CLASS_PROPERTY = "___class";

    private final Gson gson;

    private StaticTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    static <T> TypeAdapter<Class<T>> getStaticTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
        return new StaticTypeAdapter<>(gson);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Class<T> value)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            final Iterator<Field> iterator = Stream.of(value.getFields())
                    .filter(f -> isStatic(f.getModifiers()))
                    .iterator();
            out.beginObject();
            while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
                final Field field = iterator.next();
                out.name(field.getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);
                final Object fieldValue = field.get(null);
                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
                final TypeAdapter<Object> adapter = (TypeAdapter) gson.getAdapter(field.getType());
                adapter.write(out, fieldValue);
            }
            out.name(TARGET_CLASS_PROPERTY);
            out.value(value.getName());
            out.endObject();
        } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            Class<?> type = null;
            in.beginObject();
            final Map<String, JsonElement> buffer = new HashMap<>();
            while ( in.peek() != END_OBJECT ) {
                final String property = in.nextName();
                switch ( property ) {
                case TARGET_CLASS_PROPERTY:
                    type = Class.forName(in.nextString());
                    break;
                default:
                    // buffer until the target class name is known
                    if ( type == null ) {
                        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> adapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
                        final JsonElement jsonElement = adapter.read(in);
                        buffer.put(property, jsonElement);
                    } else {
                        // flush the buffer
                        if ( !buffer.isEmpty() ) {
                            for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : buffer.entrySet() ) {
                                final Field field = type.getField(e.getKey());
                                final Object value = gson.getAdapter(field.getType()).read(in);
                                field.set(null, value);
                            }
                            buffer.clear();
                        }
                        final Field field = type.getField(property);
                        if ( isStatic(field.getModifiers()) ) {
                            final TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(field.getType());
                            final Object value = adapter.read(in);
                            field.set(null, value);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            in.endObject();
            // flush the buffer
            if ( type != null && !buffer.isEmpty() ) {
                for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : buffer.entrySet() ) {
                    final Field field = type.getField(e.getKey());
                    final Object value = gson.fromJson(e.getValue(), field.getType());
                    field.set(null, value);
                }
                buffer.clear();
            }
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            final Class<T> castType = (Class) type;
            return castType;
        } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ex ) {
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Example use:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getStaticTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
final String json = gson.toJson(DyescapeCOREConfiguration.class);
out.println("DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=" + DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID);
// ---
DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID = "whatever";
out.println("DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=" + DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID);
// ---
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Class<DyescapeCOREConfiguration> configurationClass = gson.fromJson(json, Class.class);
//    ^--- this is awful, omitting a useless assignment is even worse
out.println("DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=" + DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID);
```

Output:

> DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=012fa795-abd8-4b91-b6f5-bab67f73ae17
>   DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=whatever
>   DyescapeCOREConfiguration.ServerID=012fa795-abd8-4b91-b6f5-bab67f73ae17

However, I still recommend you to avoid the idea of static fields (de)serialization.

Comment: How would I get the instance of a child configuration class from the abstract DyescapeConfiguration class? As you can probably see, I'm making it fully dynamic. It should export the child class to JSON, dynamicly.

Comment: @DennisvanderVeeke I do believe you're doing it in a wrong way. However, see the answer update. Answering your commenting question I could say only that you're doing `this.getClass()` -- `this` is already an instance you're looking for.

Comment: I am yet to test your code out, but it seems legit at first sight. You've mentioned a few times why I should avoid static fields. Mind explaining me why?

Comment: @DennisvanderVeeke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil -- here's an example discussion. `static`s (methods) also suppress virtual dispatching at the very root.

Comment: Another point even closer to the reality is, I think, if you take a look at the `gson.fromJson` in my answer, you see the assignment is totally useless since all `Class` instances are created by JVM, and the adapter just returns what JVM created. You have 0 benefit of that variable. If you remove the variable, then the assignment-designed `fromJson` method returns a value into the void, but also _changes global state silently not giving you even a sign_. It's a treacherous gotcha, isn't it? Just imagine: if there were a static `toString` that could modify the enclosing class...

Comment: Hi, your comments are very usefull. I followed your advise and **got rid of the static variable**, it is now only available after using the `get()` method that simply returns the instance of the class. The current problem right now is; Using `this.getClass()` from the abstract DyescapeConfiguration class still causes the error. 

Code: `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.json");
   gson.toJson(this.getClass(), writer);
   writer.close();`

Comment: @DennisvanderVeeke Since you have removed the static modifier, you don't have to (de)serialize a class now: `.toJson(this.getClass(), writer)` should now be `.toJson(this, writer)`.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks alot! Have as much upvotes as I can give.

Comment: @DennisvanderVeeke I'm glad I could help you. You're welcome!

Comment: well explanation and  also agreed to avoid static field while serialization and deserialization.