# Printing a Final Class on the console in json

Tags: java, json

I am trying to print a final class with static fields on the console, in json format.   I am using eclipse.

Stats is a final class that keeps track of object instances that are created or archived.  E.g. number of Member instances, number of localities instances etc.

```
    public final class Stats {

        public static Integer numMembers = 0;
        public static Integer numLocalities = 0;
        public static Integer numTowns = 0;

        public static void incrementMembers () { numMembers ++; }
        public static void incrementLocalities () { numLocalities ++; }
        public static void incrementTowns () { numTowns ++; }
    }
```

I ran into problems when I tried to print in json.  It does not recognize Stats as an Object instance, which is understandable.  Is there a way to print the current state of the Stats class in json?

```
public static void print () {

    System.out.println(GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(Stats));
}
```

Comment: What is `DBStats`?  It's also unclear what you mean by "does not recognise Stats as a class and wants to create a local variable".

Comment: `toJson()` works on object ***instances***, not classes.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, Sorry editing issue.   Changed it to Stats.

Comment: @JimGarrison, Thanks for your reply.  Is there another way to print the current version/state of Stats.

Comment: I expect you will want to read [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14644860/18157)

Comment: I fear you are misunderstanding the purpose of `static` (class variables) and their relationship to serialization.  You haven't really given us enough information to understand what you are trying to do and why those variables are static.

Comment: @JimGarrison.   I added more details to my question about Stats.   Stats is a overall class, where the Program/Model statistics are maintained.   It has static fields because they are shared by all API's and threads..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach will not work with JSON (or any other) serialization, and cannot be made to work the way you want.

A global static object is an anti-pattern as it introduces unwanted coupling into your codebase.  There are two approaches to solve this problem, Dependency Injection and Singleton.  In both cases, your "statistics" object is a normal object with non-static fields.

```
public final class Stats {

    private int numMembers = 0;
    private int numLocalities = 0;
    private int numTowns = 0;

    public void incrementMembers () { numMembers ++; }
    public void incrementLocalities () { numLocalities ++; }
    public void incrementTowns () { numTowns ++; }

    // Getters...
}
```

(not sure why you were using `Integer`, it's not necessary here)

Dependency Injection requires a framework like Spring. If you're not already using Spring then it may be too much change and learning-curve all at one time for you to take on.  But it is the best way long-term.  An explanation of DI is beyond the scope of an answer here, but the principle is that the framework takes care of instantiating the object and "injecting" it wherever it is needed.

The lighter-weight alternative is the "singleton" pattern (look it up, it is well-documented), where the object contains one static member reference to the single instance that gets created the first time you access it.

```
public final class Stats {
    ...
    private static Stats instance = null;
    public static Stats getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Stats();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

(The above is simplistic and ignores threading concerns, study the pattern before using)

Then wherever you need a reference to the (single) `Stats` instance you do

```
Stats stats = Stats.getInstance();
```

In either case you have a real ***instance*** that can be serialized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   This will work for me.   I think, I understand the pattern based on some reading.   Just to clarify - For any updates to the fields, I will have to do it via e.g. Stats.getInstance().incrementMembers().

Comment: Yes, or just do `Stats stats = Stats.getInstance();` at the start of the scope (i.e. start of method or as a private member variable) and use the reference `stats` locally.